# My UIView animation is jerky - how can I optimize the following code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview

On the simulator, my animation method runs smoothly. Unfortunately it seems to be very jerky running on an iPhone 4.

I'm not 100% sure of what the best and fastest way to do animations - so any tips on how I can optimize or completely modify my code to speed up this animation would be most appreciated!

**Notes:**

It's already on the main thread so does that make the 'dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())' call irrelevant or unhelpful?

Is there a way to pre buffer this animation?

Is there a way to see exactly which part of the code is doing most of the slowing down?

There are only about 3 or 4 views in extensionView.subviews.

I've compiled with -Os.

```
- (void)extendWithAnimation:(BOOL)animated; {

    isExtended = YES;
    extensionView.hidden = NO;
    topShadowView.hidden = NO;

    topShadowView.frame = CGRectMake(0, defaultHeight, topShadowView.frame.size.width, topShadowView.frame.size.height);
    topShadowView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, topShadowView.frame.size.width, 0);
    extensionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, defaultHeight - 8, DEVICE_WIDTH, extensionHeight + 8);
    extensionView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, DEVICE_WIDTH, 0);

    for (UIView *view in extensionView.subviews) {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -(extensionHeight+8));
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (animated) {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
            [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        }

        extensionView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, DEVICE_WIDTH, extensionHeight + 8);
        topShadowView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, topShadowView.frame.size.width, extensionHeight + 8);

        for (UIView *view in extensionView.subviews) {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }

        if (animated) {
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    });   
}
```

**Solution:**

Solved (thanks Aaron!).

Rendered shadows kill animation big time! Don't use any core graphics shadow properties if you're planning on animating - in my case just a few shadows reduced the frame rate three fold.

Comment: CALayer shadow drawing performance is massively improved if you specify a shadowPath for the layer, you could try that before ripping out all of your code...

Comment: @jrturton interesting, unfortunately that won't really work for a UITextView which is where the issue is for me. But for others with similar problems that sounds like a very good point!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Well, if the code is already on the main queue then using dispatch_async is only going to have overhead.
2. I don't know if this will help (I kind of doubt it), but you might try using `[UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:{ code... }];`
3. In my past attempts to deal with shadows they've tended to have a pretty big performance hit.  You might consider leaving shadows and layers alone and instead create a resizable shadow PNG that you can use in a UIImageView placed behind the the view you want shadowed.

Comment: Thanks! The shadow view is actually a PNG like you suggest, although some of the involved subviews have rendered shadows so perhaps that is the problem - will try soon :)

Comment: I agree that the dispatch_async() in unnecessary, but GCD is really, really fast; I'd be surprised if that's adding any meaningful lag.

Comment: @Jordan Probably, I'd first just remove the shadows and see how it performs.  If it does, then you can add them back in as PNG's and try again.

Comment: I also agree that GCD is fast and performance hit should be negligible.

Comment: GCD probably isn't adding lag, but it's definitely pointless. All it is doing is delaying the animation from starting by 1/60th second. You can't do UIView animation on a background thread, and you shouldn't try.

Comment: Thanks, shadows were most of the issue, along with some needless core data stuff happening in the background concurrently. The frame rate tripled just by removing 2 views with shadows... insane!

Comment: Your 3rd point works for me. The shadow was creating performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Run your code through Instruments (start with Time Profiler).  What calls are taking the most time during the animation?

Once you have profiled it, also run it through the Core Animation instrument and enable coloring of off-screen rendering and of non-opaque content.  This will help isolate common graphics problems.

I also notice you mention shadows.  If you are using the CALayer shadow properties, that's likely killing your performance.  But we need more information to really nail this down.